# Can't find BaseWaveAppLayer.h: no such file or directory

Tags: veins

I have the following includes in `TutorialAppl.h`:

```
#include "veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.h"
#include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.h"
#include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h"
```

When I tried to build the project, there is a fatal error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type fatal error:
>   veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.h: No such file
>   or directory  TutorialAppl.h  /VeinsTutorial/src  line 11 C/C++ Problem

I am using veins 4.6. The project is under the root directory of Project Explorer.

what should I do , thank you very much!

Comment: Even I added the complete include path in makemake options, still the same error. 
opp_makemake --nolink -f --deep -O out -KVEINS_PROJ=/home/michael/Downloads/veins-veins-4.6 -I$$\(VEINS_PROJ\)/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p -I$$\(VEINS_PROJ\)/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci -I. -Isrc -L$$\(VEINS_PROJ\)/out/$$\(CONFIGNAME\)/src -lveins -d src -X.

Comment: I use make V=1 to show all the commands, you can see the .h files have been included
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/michael/omnetpp-5.1.1/michael/test/src'
.....   -I/home/michael/Downloads/veins-veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p -I/home/michael/Downloads/veins-veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci -I/home/michael/omnetpp-5.1.1/include -o ../out/gcc-debug/src/TutorialAppl.o TutorialAppl.cpp
In file included from TutorialAppl.cpp:4:0:
TutorialAppl.h:13:10: fatal error:

Comment: It has been solved by myself. 
just add ***/veins4.6/src in the include path in makemake options/compile, then the compiler will add ***/veins4.6/src + veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/, then it becomes the complete path of the .h file.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: You might want to post your solution again as an actual answer and mark that as solution. In this way, other users can benefit from your solution.

Comment: I'd like to share my experience. But how? Can I post the solution in comment？ Sorry I am a beginner here.

Comment: As I said, you can post it as an answer to your own question and then mark the answer as solution. In that way, this question will be marked solved and other user can benefit from that.